# Showing the product of two processes is a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $B_{t}$ be a Brownian Motion, let $Y_{t}=exp\Big(\int_{0}^{t}g_{s}dB_{s}-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}g_{s}^2ds\Big)$ for a progressively measurable $g$.

Let $X_{t}=B_{t}-\int_{0}^{t}g_{s}ds$.

I want to show that $X_{t}Y_{t}$ is a martingale.

Ito's Lemma shows that $Y_{t}$ is a martingale. I want to compute $d(X_{t}Y_{t})$ but I do not know the cross-variation of both processes. It has to be $\int_{0}^{t}Y_{s}g_{s}ds$, but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, $$\,\mathrm d X_t=-g_t\,\mathrm d t+\,\mathrm d B_t,$$
and $$\,\mathrm d Y_t=Y_tg_t\,\mathrm d B_t.$$
Therefore $$\,\mathrm d \left<X,Y\right>_t=Y_tg_t\,\mathrm d t.$$

Comment: How do you conclude the cross variation from knowing $dX_{t}$ and $dY_{t}$? Sorry, I must be missing something really basic here...

Comment: One can prove that if $\,\mathrm d X_t=\alpha _t\,\mathrm d t+\beta_t\,\mathrm d B_t$ and $dY_t=\gamma _t\,\mathrm d t+\delta _t\,\mathrm d B_t$, then $\,\mathrm d \left<X,Y\right>_t=\beta _t\delta _t\,\mathrm d t.$

Comment: I really need a proper course on Ito calculus. Next semester! But thanks anyway :)